# How to change font size and colour in androidx drawer layout widget

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer, navigationview

See the below image I want to change the font size and color of marked footer area text which is placed in menu. I do not want to use `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`, that I know I can change it by using this. Please help me.

OR

If there is any other way to add a footer area as like the same as we set the header area attribute (`app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"`)?

Here is my main XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/menuTextStyle"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is activity_main_drawer.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_pets"
            android:title="My Pets" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_stores"
            android:title="My Stores" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_products"
            android:title="My Products" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_promotions"
            android:title="Promotions" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faqs"
            android:title="FAQs" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:title="My Account" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
            android:title="Notifications" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:title="About" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:visible="false" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_forum"
            android:title="Forum" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
            android:title="Privacy/Terms" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/subtitle2"
                android:title="by:">
                <menu>
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_footer1"
                        android:checkableBehavior="none"
                        android:title="by:" />
                    <item
                        android:id="@+id/nav_footer2"
                        android:checkableBehavior="none"
                        android:title="afterdarkgrafx.com" />
                </menu>
            </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use:

- [RelativeSizeSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan) for setting a percentage of the default menu item text size.

```
// Java
private void setMenuTextSize(MenuItem item, float proportion) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(item.getTitle().toString());
    spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(proportion), 
                          0, spanString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    item.setTitle(spanString);
}

// Kotlin
private fun setMenuTextSize(item: MenuItem, proportion: Float) {
    val spanString = SpannableString(item.title.toString())
    spanString.setSpan(
        RelativeSizeSpan(proportion),
        0, spanString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    item.title = spanString
}
```

- [AbsoluteSizeSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan) for setting text size to physical pixels.

```
// Java
private void setMenuTextSize(MenuItem item, int textSize) {
    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(item.getTitle().toString());
    spanString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize), 0, spanString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    item.setTitle(spanString);
}

// Kotlin
private fun setMenuTextSize(item: MenuItem, textSize: Int) {
    val spanString = SpannableString(item.title.toString())
    spanString.setSpan(
        AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize),
        0,
        spanString.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    item.title = spanString
}
```

To convert from sp to pixel:

```
// Java
public static int spToPx(int sp) {
    return (int) (sp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
}

// Kotlin 
fun spToPx(sp: Int) = (sp * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.scaledDensity).toInt()
```

Applying that on your menu:

```
// Java
private void reduceItemSize(NavigationView navView) {
    Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.subtitle2);
    SubMenu subMenu = item.getSubMenu();
    MenuItem footer1Item = subMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_footer1);
    MenuItem footer2Item = subMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_footer2);

    // Using RelativeSizeSpan
    setMenuTextSize(footer1Item, 0.8f);
    setMenuTextSize(footer2Item, 0.8f);

    // Using AbsoluteSizeSpan
    setMenuTextSize(footer1Item, spToPx(12));
    setMenuTextSize(footer2Item, spToPx(12));
}

// Kotlin
private fun reduceItemSize(navView: NavigationView) {
    val menu = navView.menu
    val item = menu.findItem(R.id.subtitle2)
    val subMenu = item.subMenu
    val footer1Item = subMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_footer1)
    val footer2Item = subMenu.findItem(R.id.nav_footer2)

    // Using RelativeSizeSpan
    setMenuTextSize(footer1Item, 0.8f)
    setMenuTextSize(footer2Item, 0.8f)

    // Using AbsoluteSizeSpan
    setMenuTextSize(footer1Item, spToPx(12))
    setMenuTextSize(footer2Item, spToPx(12))
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gitesh Cool.. also please notice there is [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan) that you can try to change the color of the menuItem

Comment: will use ForegroundColorSpan for change the color, Thanks !

Comment: It works well, Thanks !